downloadButton in leaflet popup using modules
I'm building an R shiny application that has a downloadButton in a leaflet popup to download data specific to the area clicked. I was able to implement this following this post. My approach seems to be failing after I've converted the leaflet map and download button into modules.
The downloadButton works on the first polygon click but becomes unresponsive when I click on a additional polygons.
Below is a simplified example of the app code:
app.R
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(dplyr)

# https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2023/shp/cb_2023_us_state_20m.zip
state_data <- st_read("cb_2023_us_state_20m.shp")

ui <- fluidPage(
  leaflet_map_ui("map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  selected_state <- leaflet_map_server("map")
  download_state_server("button", selected_state)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

module_download_state.R
download_state_ui <- function(id){
  downloadButton(NS(id, "downloadData"), "download state data")
}

download_state_server <- function(id, state_fips){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = paste0("data_",state_fips(),".csv"),
      content = function(file){
        state_data %>% 
          filter(STATEFP == state_fips()) %>% 
          write.csv(file)
      }
    )
  })
}

module_leaflet_map.R
leaflet_map_ui <- function(id){
  leafletOutput(NS(id, "map"))
}

leaflet_map_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        setView(lng = -98.35, lat = 39.5, zoom=5) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = state_data, 
                    layerId = state_data$STATEFP, 
                    popup = paste0("<div id='dl-popup'>",
                                   state_data$NAME,
                                   "<br>",
                                   download_state_ui("button"),
                                   "</div>") ) %>% 
        htmlwidgets::onRender(HTML("
         function(el, x) {
            this.on('popupopen', function() {
               Shiny.bindAll('#dl-popup');
            });
            this.on('popupclose', function() {
               Shiny.unbindAll('#dl-popup');
            });
         }"))
      
    })
    
    # update selected fips based on map click
    selected_fips <- reactiveVal("00")
    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      selected_fips(input$map_shape_click$id)
    })
    
    return(selected_fips)
  })
}


You have problems with duplicated ids, see e.g. this answer for how to generate buttons with unique ids. Another possibility is to use a pointerenter event as in this answer. This works for your case too, however, then the button gets the enabled look only if you hover on the popup, not if you are outside.

@Jan I think I'm missing where I have duplicated ids. The example above has one button. pointerenter worked before I converted to shiny modules but now when I use it the button is inactive on the first selection of the leaflet map.

Yes, it has one button, but look into the JS console in a browser what happens if you are not closing the popup via 'x', but rather click onto another state. Are you observing the problem from your question also if you always close the popup via 'x'? I don't see it then, I only get it when the popup is not 'properly closed'. Also pointerenter works for me with your code with the limitation described in my first comment.

@Jan I see what you're saying now. Yes I get the `The following ID was repeated:

"button-downloadData":message regardless of whether or not I properly close the popup.pointerenteris not working for me. I tried it this way:   htmlwidgets::onRender(HTML("
function(el, x) {
this.on('pointerenter', #button-downloadData, function() {
Shiny.bindAll('#dl-popup');
});
this.on('pointerleave', #button-downloadData, function() {
Shiny.unbindAll('#dl-popup');
});
}"))`


This is not the right syntax for pointerenter and pointerleave, can you please try htmlwidgets::onRender(HTML("function(el, x) {$('body').on('pointerenter', '#dl-popup', function() {Shiny.bindAll('#dl-popup');}); $('body').on('pointerleave', '#dl-popup', function() {Shiny.unbindAll('#dl-popup');});}")). What is your experience about this? It works good for me.

Thanks! Yes that's working for me in the example. Unfortunately I think I made my example a little too simplified. In my use case the popup with the downloadButton module would be created in a leafletProxy('map') call when new data is added. The button is responsive when I click different polygons but the download fails The file at ... was loaded over an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. I think I need to do some more troubleshooting.
